# Displaying jpegPhoto attribute from LDAP in Websphere Portal

Tags: ldap, websphere-portal

I have a requirement wherein I need to display details of users after searching from LDAP using PUMA API.

I'm having troubling displaying the jpegPhoto of the user.

Here's what I'm doing:
First I'm querying the user by using:
PumaLocator.findUsersByAttribute(uid, user);

After that we get a User list Object.
For each user, we fetch all the attributes which is in the form of a Map.

I'm getting the following value for while retrieving the jpegPhoto:

map.get("jpegPhoto") --> *[B@7a2f8a54*

It seems that the Puma API returns a Binary string. Does anyone know how to display this in the portlet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: This is the result of calling `byte[].toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it more likely this is a `byte[]` array than a string.

You can probably base64 encode this binary into an encoded string and use it in an HTML image tag.

```
byte[] photoBytes = (byte[]) map.get("jpegPhoto");
String encodedPhoto = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(photoBytes);
```

Then later, perhaps in a JSP (example assumes JSTL variable in scope named `encodedPhoto`):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,${encodedPhoto}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing this is to access the image through the portal service servlet instead of using your own servlet: `/wps/um/secure/users/profiles/[oid]/jpegPhoto`, in which you replace `[oid]` with the ObjectID of the user. This ID string can be obtained using `IdentificationMgr.getIdentification().serialize(user.getObjectID())`

The photo of the current user you can access using: `/wps/um/secure/currentuser/profile/jpegPhoto`

Answer (score 0):

Portal is giving you data as byte array. It will never give you as URL.
You can write a servlet which will write this byte array to output stream.
Use that servlet URL as src of  tag. It will start rendering on browser.

FYI, you can't print byte array to browser and expect it to treat as image.
Image or any other files has to come as a resource not as content.